# Combining a split tar file with minimal temporary disk space use

Tags: linux, shell, tar

I have a 400 GB tar file split into 1 GB chunks with `split`, like file.tar.aa, file.tar.ab, etc.

The entire .tar file can be reconstructed with `cat *`. I would like to unsplit the file and end up with the single 400 GB file, but I have only 15 GB free and so a simple `cat * > file.tar` will run out of space.

Can I do this with a minimum of temporary space?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would work:

```bash
#!/bin/bash                               
mv first_part.aa merged.tar             
for file in $(cat list);                                     
do                                        
cat $file >> merged.tar               
rm $file                                  
done
```